# eBay API CompleteSale call for multiple items

Tags: php, xml, ebay-api

Currently I have a system which retrieves a list of orders from eBay (using the `GetOrders` API call) to do some processing. System will display the list of orders for users to check to update status to Shipped (using `CompleteSale` API call).

The problem I am having now is that the process of updating the status using the API is kind of slow because the `CompleteSale` is being called for each order (possible that user check 1000 records to update status to Shipped at one time). Is it possible to send multiple items in one `CompleteSale` call or is there other API calls that is able to ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply add several ItemIDs and TransactionIDs to one request like this (for php)

```
$item_id_1 = 1234567890;
$item_id_2 = 0987654321;
$feedback = 'Thanks for a smooth transaction!';

$transaction_id_1 = 771234567819;
$transaction_id_2 = 770987654319;

$requestXmlBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
$requestXmlBody .= '<CompleteSaleRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">';

$requestXmlBody .= "<ItemID>$item_id_1</ItemID>";
$requestXmlBody .= "<ItemID>$item_id_2</ItemID>";

$requestXmlBody .= "<FeedbackInfo>";
$requestXmlBody .= "<CommentText>$feedback_text</CommentText>";
$requestXmlBody .= "<CommentType>Positive</CommentType>";
$requestXmlBody .= "</FeedbackInfo>";

$requestXmlBody .= "<Shipped>true</Shipped>";
$requestXmlBody .= "<TransactionID>$transaction_id_1</TransactionID>";
$requestXmlBody .= "<TransactionID>$transaction_id_2</TransactionID>";

$requestXmlBody .= "<RequesterCredentials><eBayAuthToken>$userToken</eBayAuthToken></RequesterCredentials>";
$requestXmlBody .= '</CompleteSaleRequest>';
```

I think it should also work if you use orderIDs instead! Please be aware that you cannot use multiple buyerUserIDs (for the recipient). Use only itemID/transactionID pairs.

This is based off the eBay PHP sample code provided here:

https://ebay.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1876/~/getorders-php-code-sample

Just change the call to what you need!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the sample !! :) i shall test it out !!