# How do I send many http requests at the same time?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, web-services, windows-services

I have an eBay account. To make updating my products easily, I created a windows service in C#. It waits (by `FileSystemWatcher`) for an xml file and once a file is appeared, a service reads it and sends requests to eBay server through their API. A file might hold about 1000-3000 rows.

Previously I used to create **12** threads to make it faster. I don't know why I chose **12** threads,  I thought that was enough amount: not too much and not too little.

So here is a method how I looked like before (bit dirty, **12** should be a constant)

```
private static void UpdateAsync(IEnumerable<ProductInfo> products)
        {
            ProductInfo[] productsInfo = items.ToArray();
            Thread[] threads = new Thread[12];
            bool sendPartialy = productsInfo .Length > 12;
            int delta = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < productsInfo.Length; i++)
            {
                if (sendPartialy )
                {
                    if (i != 0 && i % 12 == 0)
                    {
                        WaitForExecutedThreads(threads);
                        delta = 12 * (i / 12);
                    }
                }

                ProductInfo product = ProductInfo[i];
                threads[i - delta] = new Thread(_ => product.UpdateItem(context));
                threads[i - delta].Start();
            }

            WaitForExecutedThreads(threads);
        }
```

Then they told me that using threads are not necessary because of **only one** network interface: it's narrow to allow 12 https requests be executed at the same time and thus, each of a thread will be waiting for another one.

That's why I decided not to use multi-threading at all and just use a simple requests like that:

```
    var itemInfoLights = new List<ItemInfoLight>();
    foreach (var p in productsInfo )
    {
       p.UpdateItem(context);
    }
```

I know, it's too bad to send all request separately because each of them has their own headers, etc... That's not efficient.

Well, what is the right approach to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't need the CPU during this network operation, creating new threads isn't the optimal choice.  (When CPU is the actual issue, you generally want only 1 thread per processor.  So, 2 or 4 threads would be ideal.)

If you had an async version of the `UpdateItem` method, you could call it as many times as you have items to update, then handle the completion in a callback function.  This would be much more efficient, since you would not be starting threads that don't really do anything, but you would be executing multiple requests at nearly the same time.

In the event that you don't have an async version of the method, using threads will be the only easy way to get side-by-side update calls.  You might use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` instead.  That takes advantage of threads which are already available, avoiding the cost of spinning up new threads every time.

Comment: I disagree about 1 thread per processor.  Depending upon what's running you might have 100s of threads currently active in any given system; and that's okay.  The question is one of where the constraint really is.  If the thread comes up, issues it's request, and spends a lot of time waiting for a response from the network interface then you could easily have 50+ going at once whose total execution time is drastically lower than just running 4; even on a single "processor" machine.

Comment: @ChrisLively: If you read my statement again, you'll notice that I said "When CPU is the actual issue...".  That means, if your CPU is the bottleneck, one thread per core is the most efficient.

Answer (score 3):

The cost of starting a thread is insignificant compared to the time to execute a web service call. What's worked well for me is to `Queue` a `Thread` instance for each request you want to send using a worker method that invokes a callback once the web service call completes. Threads only consume resources when they're started, not when they're just instantiated.

I then use a supervisor class that dequeues a thread, starts it, and then adds it to a `Dictionary` keyed by the threads' `ManagedThreadId`. This is repeated until you reach your maximum number of twelve concurrent connections. As each thread finishes, it invokes the callback method back to the supervisor, which then removes the thread from the `Dictionary` and launches another queued thread. Once the `Queue` and `Dictionary` are empty you're done.

If you wire a UI app to your service you can adjust the thread limit while monitoring your throughput and the queued and active threads so you can play with it in real-time.

You should also set the `maxconnection` property in your app.config to something like 100 to give you room to experiment.

Comment: +1: especially for the maxconnection property.  It's often overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

As I guess you want maximum efficiency so I advice you to use .**Net Thread Pool**. There is `ThreadPool` class which will allocate maximum threads from the pc. There is many example over the web.

[one of them here. msdn with example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973903.aspx)

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(YourRequestFunctionName, parameterObject);

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the `**only one** network interface` part means.  Sounds like some bad advice.

Even browsers typically issue 5 to 10 simultaneous requests when pulling down a web page in order to grab the various parts (css, javascript, images, the page itself..).  So, having 12 threads ought to be just fine.

Regarding the headers etc, you can't avoid that for individual requests.  The only other way is if the API allows you to send multiple requests in a single transaction.  I'm not familiar with the eBay API, however I would imagine that they do support it.

You might look at this question for a hint: [CompleteSale Ebay API for multiple items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349235/completesale-ebay-api-for-multiple-items)

Comment: Regards to 12: do you suggest me to use exactly 12 threads or more or less?

Comment: @AlanDert I would suggest that through testing your app you'll find the right number to do.  The number of threads is very much system dependent.  For example, having 12 threads running on a machine with an old 386 processor is probably not worthwhile, whereas 12 threads on a modern CPU that is doing nothing else is under utilizing the system.   Also, the eBay API itself might have restrictions on the number of simultaneous requests you can make (probably not, but you never know).  You'll have to do some performance testing to find the right magic number.

Answer (score 0):

When I do something like this I use the asynchronous HttpRequest methods and it works for me. Look into HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse and HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream.

Also more info : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86wf6409(VS.71).aspx

I think this is the right approach

Comment: ebay doesn't have BeginXXXAsyn methods.