# Best way to send http requests at same time

Tags: c#, java

Should be an easy question - I want to send two http requests at identical times without much care in what is being returned. My goal is to have packet A and packet B arrive at destination at exact times ignoring latency.

I'm familiar with Python and C# but no expert. Does anyone know software (irc, nettools, etc) that could do this or if it could be done easily in C? I've asked about doing it in Python but everything seems asynchronous. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Check this out:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732469/how-do-i-send-many-http-requests-at-the-same-time

Comment: It is not really clear to me whether you want the requests to be sent or received at the same time. Also, you won't be able to set the exact times of these events, and they will most probably occur in unspecified order.

Comment: Yep I know its very hard to tell when they arrive.  maybe I will try just sending the request as fast as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to do this in Java / C? If there any reason you can't use a simple shell script and wget to send two HTTP requests one after another?

You won't be able able to send the requests at exactly the same time but you can send them directly one after another without any wait / extra code.

If you want more information on wget you can find it here: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?wget

Comment: Yeah it doesnt matter the lanuage,  I can learn quickly.  Im proficient in python but wasnt sure if there is an easier way to ensure simultaneous sending.

Answer (score 0):

I know that [OpenSTA](http://opensta.org/) will do it, as will a bunch of other tools on [THIS](http://www.testingfaqs.org/t-load.html) site.   Then, you can trace those requests using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or Fiddler and then you will know exactly when the requests arrive compared to each other.

Elliot is right though, a shell script, if you have the skill, is the easiest way.

Comment: YOu marked your question with "C#" . Perhaps Powershell is a good way to go for you, although it is sorta Visual Basic syntactically.